# foreach causing out of bounds error in Java when used with array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I want to print all elements in array using foreach loop

```
int[] array={1,2,3,4,5};
   for(int i:array)
       System.out.println(array[i]);
```

And compilers gives me this error/warning

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

but when I  print something else

```
int[] array={1,2,3,4,5};
   for(int i:array)
       System.out.println("Print something");
```

It writes "Print something" five times and gives no warning/error.

I assume it has to do something that first element in array has index 0, but I am not sure.

Can someone explain why ?

Comment: Are you sure this is **exactly** the code that cause the problem?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès `array[i]` with the for each loop is the problem.

Comment: Oh yes!!! I missed the point! Stupid I am...

Comment: `i` iterates over the values not the index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first chunk of code, you are *not* printing all elements in the array.  You are going through all elements in the array and for each element you are printing the entry in the array corresponding to that element's value.

What you want is this:

```
int[] array={1,2,3,4,5};
   for(int i:array)
       System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating the contents of the array which is assigned to `i`, so the code translates to

```
System.out.println(array[1]);
System.out.println(array[2]);
System.out.println(array[3]);
System.out.println(array[4]);
System.out.println(array[5]);   // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```